# Opentelemetry Java InstrumentationModule - How to use "com.google.gson" as Helper class?

Tags: java, otel

I have an Otel `InstrumentationModule` that requires `com.google.gson` library, from what I understand from [Otel Documentation](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/contributing/writing-instrumentation-module.md) in order to inject `com.google.json` I need to override `getAdditionalHelperClassNames` function with -

```
  @Override
  public List<String> getAdditionalHelperClassNames() {
    return Arrays.asList(
        "com.google.gson.Gson",
  }
```

My issue is that `com.google.gson` is not a single class, there are a lot of classes inside this library, and I don't want to specify all the classes in the correct order to make that work.

Is there an option the inject a full library instead of separate classes ?